# Rendering tree with D3, data not being set up properly as a hierarchy?

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js, tree

I am trying to create a radial tree in a React component, following this :  https://observablehq.com/@d3/radial-tree/2
(except I don't want the text labels, I want nodes)

My data looks like:
`[{`
`id: 1,`
`parentId: null,`
`title: “rootnode”},`
`{`
`id: 2,`
`parentId: 1,`
`title: “child1"`
`},`
`{`
`id: 3,`
`parentId: 1,`
`title: “child2”},`
`etc`
`]`

I can also query an array with any datapoint’s children with Sequelize
But no matter what I try it seems the data is not read as hierarchical?
the .stratify() function throws a “no root node on stratify”
error
the .hierarchy(data) function doesn’t throw any errors but nothing appears on the page.
I think the issue is that my data is not set up correctly, but I have tried so many variants and nothing works.
Right now when I console.log the root (in the draw function) it prints a "node" element that just seems to have all my data as a parameter.

My Tree component looks like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";



export default function Tree({ data }) {

  const svgRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {

    const tree = d3.cluster()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, Math.min(928, 928) / 2 - 30])
    .separation((a, b) => (a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth);
    
    const root = d3.hierarchy(data)
  
    draw(tree(root));
  }, [data]);


  function draw(root) {
    console.log(root)

  
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)
    console.log(svg)
 


        svg.append("g")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "#555")
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.4)
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
          .selectAll()
          .data(root.links())
          .join("path")
          .attr("d", d3.linkRadial()
            .angle(d => d.x)
            .radius(d => d.y));


        svg.append("g")
         .selectAll()
         .data(root.descendants())
         .join("circle")
          // .attr("transform", d => `rotate(${d.x * 180 / Math.PI - 90}) translate(${d.y},0)`)
          .attr("fill", d => d.children ? "#555" : "#999")
          .attr("r", 2.5);

          svg.append("g")
           .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
           .attr("stroke-width", 3)
           .selectAll()
           .data(root.descendants())

      return svg.node();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <svg ref={svgRef} id="myTree" width="1000" height="1000"></svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

For your data to be hierarchical, it needs to be an object representing the root node and needs to have a *children* attribute with an array of all the root node’s children. Those children can then contain further children.

An example from the D3 documentation (https://d3js.org/d3-hierarchy/hierarchy):

```
const data = {
  name: "Eve",
  children: [
    {name: "Cain"},
    {name: "Seth", children: [{name: "Enos"}, {name: "Noam"}]},
    {name: "Abel"},
    {name: "Awan", children: [{name: "Enoch"}]},
    {name: "Azura"}
  ]
};
```

So for your above data to be hierarchical, it should be in the following format:

```
{
    name: “rootnode”,
    id: 1,
    parentId: null,
    children: [
        {name: “child1“,
        id: 2,
        parentId: 1},
        {name: “child2”
        id: 3,
        parentId: 1}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My data was not set up properly which is why this was not working.
I had various typos with the ids with the data I was trying to force. Just silly old human error.